# Breadcrumb trail shows incorrect trail?

Tags: php, wordpress

Why the following code would cause my breadcrumb trail to show the same post link in the breadcrumbs no matter what page you are on in the site?

I have been stuck on this issue for ages now and just cannot figure it out...

See what I mean [here](http://alanbrandt.com).

```
<!-- Loops through Stories and returns images -->

    <ul style="width: 1520px">                                    
    <?php
        global $post;
            $category_id = get_cat_ID('stories');
            $args = array( 'numberposts' => 9, 'offset'=> 0, 'category'=> $category_id );
            $myposts = get_posts( $args );
        foreach( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
            <!-- stories -->   
            <li>
                <figure>
                      <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) : // Check if thumbnail exists ?>    
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail(array(64,64)); // Declare pixel size you need inside the array ?></a>
                <?php endif; ?>
                </figure>
                <!-- /post thumbnail -->
                <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
          </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
         </ul> 
<!-- /Loops through Stories and returns images -->
```

Comment: Try to [reset the postdata](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata) after the `foreach`. Otherwise, there's nothing in your code breadcrumb related. What does GoogleAuthorship has to do with breadcrumbs?

Comment: Sorry that title was for another post... It is strange because the last post that is found in foreach loop is the post that shows up in all the breadcrumb trails.

Comment: BINGO... Thank you so much... the reset fixed it... :)

Comment: Ok, I'll post as an answer, glad it worked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to reset the postdata, like in [this example from the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata#Example_1):

```
<ul>
<?php
global $post;
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 5, 'offset'=> 1, 'category' => 1 );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $myposts as $post ) :
  setup_postdata($post); ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</ul>
```